# Multi-colored edges in tikz undirected graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams

I am trying to draw an undirected graph with some edges colored with two colors side-by-side. I really like [this solution suggested by Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233942/208727), but I cannot get it to work for straight edges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
    semithick,
    node distance = 2cm,
    dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}
}
\tikzset{
    side by side/.style 2 args={
    line width=2pt,
    #1,
    postaction={
        clip,postaction={draw,#2}
        }
    }
}
\tikzstyle{every state}=[draw = black,thick,fill = white,minimum size = 4mm]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=2pt,-,red!50]

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
              \node[dot] (0) {};
              \node[dot] [right of=0] (1) {};
              \node[dot] [below right of=1, yshift=15] (2) {};
              \node[dot] [below of=0] (3) {};
              \node[dot] [right of=3] (4) {};

              \path (0) edge[side by side={red!50}{blue!50},bend left] (1);
              \path (0) edge[side by side={red!50}{blue!50},bend right] (3);
              \path (1) edge (2);
              \path (1) edge[selected edge] (4);
              \path (1) edge (4);
              \path (3) edge[selected edge] (1);
              \path (3) edge (1); 
              \path (3) edge[side by side={red!50}{blue!50},bend right] (4);
              \path (4) edge[side by side={red!50}{blue!50},bend right] (2);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could try to play with node angles to begin and end your lines in two colours. And not related, but you mixed `tikzset` and `tikzstyle` here. The latter is deprecated nowadays. Try and use only `tikzset`.

Comment: @SebGlav Thank you for the suggestion! I am quite new to tikz, if you don't mind - how do I change the node angles?

Comment: Experiment with `bend right=`angle. where angle is 10 or lower. If it gets too small, the second color vanishes. This is not a solution, but maybe you can live with a weakly bent edge (unless there is a better solution).

Comment: @gernot Thank you! I settled for an 8 degree angle, it looks a bit ridiculous but it is probably more than enough for this purpose (it's only a graph to demonstrate something for my CS-assignment).

Answer (score 1):

As per [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688630) on the linked Q, the `nfold` library can help.

That said, for straight lines this could be achieved with built-in tools by just shifting the start and end points by half the line width orthogonally to the direction of the line, the same way `shift left` and `shift right`of TikZ-CD does, but `nfold` can do it, too.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  side by side/.style args={#1:#2}{
    postaction={path only,draw=#1,offset=+.5\pgflinewidth},
    postaction={path only,draw=#2,offset=+-.5\pgflinewidth}},
  side by side'/.style={path only,side by side={#1}},
  offset/.code=
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@temp
      \pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty
      \pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=+2pt, outer sep=+0pt},
  thick,
]
\node foreach[count=\i from 0]\p in {(0, 0), (2, 0), (3.5, -1), (0, -2), (2, -2)}
  [dot] (\i) at \p {};
\path
  (1) edge (2)
  [every edge/.append style={side by side=blue!50:red!50}]
      edge (3) edge (4)
  [bend right]
      edge (0)
           (0) edge (3)
                    (3) edge (4)
                             (4) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]